# __stdcall - WINAPI vs STDMETHODCALLTYPE vs APIENTRY

Tags: c++, winapi

Im reading some of the *game fix codes* which deal with memory manipulation to fix a game's "issue". I found out that the code uses 2 *macros* that are `WINAPI` and `STDMETHODCALLTYPE`. These macros all get evaluated into `__stdcall` which specifies the *calling convention* for a function. I also found out that `APIENTRY` is also another macro alias for `WINAPI`. So are there any differences between these macros ? It seems to me that they are just aliases. Why are there so many of them ?

Comment: Windows has a long history, ranging back to 16-bit Windows. The fact that these macros are identical in modern 32-bit Windows does not mean they were always identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All data types and calling conventions in the Windows API are defined as aliases (preprocessor macros or `typedef`s). This allows for a stable ABI, irrespective of the compiler or toolchain. It also allows to change the ABI without breaking existing code (e.g. when 64-bit Windows was introduced).

Both `WINAPI` and `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` expand to the same thing: `__stdcall` for x86 and nothing for everything else. So why have 2 aliases for the same thing then? Because they control the calling convention for different subsets:

- `WINAPI` specifies the calling convention for the flat C-based Windows API.
- `STDMETHODCALLTYPE`, on the other hand, controls the calling convention for COM ([Component Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model)).

COM and the Windows API are independent. Having 2 aliases to control the calling convention for either makes perfect sense. You wouldn't want to break all COM, just because you're moving to a new ABI for Win128.

Comment: Those weren't typos. There's the API ("Application Programming Interface"), and then there's the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) ("Application Binary Interface"). I really meant ABI where I wrote ABI.

Answer (score 1):

Because back in 16-bit all these were different conventions. Since x86 flat mode, everything windows-related is `__stdcall` (Push right to left, callee clears the stack). `__cdecl`, `__fastcall` also exists.

Since x64, there is practically [only one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019) and all these are ignored.

The same occurs to many other Windows elements, like WPARAM and LPARAM. Once WPARAM was 16 bit, in x86 they are both 32-bit and in x64 they are both 64 bit.